# Do we have to return value at setter?

Tags: haxe

In haxe documentation of properties, there is the example:

```
class C {

 public var x(get,set) : Int;

 function get_x(){ return 123; } 

 function set_x(value){ 
   doSomethingWith(value); 
   return 123; 
 } 
}
```

But why do we have to return a value in setter of x above? is there a good reason?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is, in Haxe, the assignment expression does return a value, eg.

```
var a;
trace(a = 3.14);//3.14
```

It is natural since we can chain assignments together:

```
var test = a = 3.14; //test will be 3.14
```

For example there is a weird class,

```
class Weird {
    public function new():Void {}
    public var x(get, set):Int;
    function get_x() return x;
    function set_x(v:Int):Int {
        x = v;
        return 123;
    }
}

var weird = new Weird();
trace(weird.x = 456); //123
trace(weird.x); //456
var test = weird.x = 456; //test will be 123
```

But of course, usually we simply return the input of the setter, because it is more logical:

```
function set_x(v:Int):Int {
    return x = v;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's right. This is an "optimization" over AS3, that will actually call the getter to determine the value of an assignment expression.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's just nice to have a setter function return the *previous* value, so you can code like this:

```
oldval=set(newval);
do_something();
set(oldval);
```

to temporarily set a new value, then restore the old one after you've finished.

Comment: No. It's the way a setter can be used, if it returns the previous value. I wanted to explain how a setter, that acts as a getter as well, can save time when you're trying to use it.